# ADD static table in Dax

Tags: variables, datatables, powerbi, dax

Dears

i tried to show data in power BI using a variable inside a measure but can not show more than one value. 
Dax code :

Measure Not Worked : `NewTable = var Data = DATATABLE("SES",STRING,{{"Name1"},{"Name2"}}) return Data`

Measure Worked : `NewTable = var Data = DATATABLE("SES",STRING,{{"Name1"}}) return Data`

Message error : a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected .

Thanks, best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A measure must return a single value, not a table. (You can use tables inside of a measure though.)

If you want a static calculated table, enter it as a New Table under the Modeling tab, instead of a measure.

```
NewTable = DATATABLE("SES",STRING,{{"Name1"},{"Name2"}})
```

Comment: i don't have a new table option because the data source from analysis service,

Comment: Are you using DirectQuery then?

Comment: Hard to say. What are you trying to use the table for?